# TCLBLEND FAILURE - Centos 6.4

Tags: java, tcl, centos6

I have been trying to use a home grown test tool and after doing an update to Centos 6.4, I am no longer able to run the tcl based tool. I am getting the following error and I have no internet access on this server. Kindly advise how do I solve this problem?

Thanks

```
"XpUtils::iload -d /usr/local/testtool/repo/package/linux-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib/tcljava1.4.1 tclblend" failed:
 couldn't load file "/usr/local/testtool/repo/package/linux-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib/tcljava1.4.1/libtclblend.so": libjava.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    while executing
"error "\"XpUtils::iload -d $dir tclblend\" failed:\n $errMsg""
    (procedure "loadtclblend" line 168)
    invoked from within
"loadtclblend /usr/local/testtool/repo/package/linux-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib/tcljava1.4.1"
    ("package ifneeded java 1.4.1" script)
    invoked from within
"package require java"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval package require $pkg"
    ("foreach" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"foreach pkg $pkgList {
   set ::${pkg}Version [eval package require $pkg]
}"
    (file "/usr/local/testtool/testtool" line 165)
```

Comment: question also on [unix & linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80007/4667)

Answer (score 0):

If you *read the error message trace*, you'll see that it says that this is all caused by:

```
libjava.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The first steps would then be to ensure that you've got a version of Java actually installed, to check that it includes the file `libjava.so`, and that the file has been indexed by the system shared library catalog.

It might also be worth checking that all its dependencies are also present and that you've got the architecture for the Tcl library and the Java library matched (e.g., both 32-bit) as those can cause odd failures when they go wrong.

Comment: It was a java issue. I installed jdk 1.7 and the issue got resolved. Thanks for your timely help.